# MouseX and MouseY not working as expected

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have an old flash app that worked ok when double the size of what it is now. The problem is, there is nowhere in the script that does math with MouseX and MouseY, i use the position directly so I do not know why its missbehaving now. These are the functions that are using the mouse.

```
        private function startPencilTool(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        pencilDraw = new Shape();
        board.addChild(pencilDraw);

        pencilDraw.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        pencilDraw.graphics.lineStyle(hardint2, activeColor, hardint);

        board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawPencilTool);
    }

    private function drawPencilTool(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        pencilDraw.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }

    private function stopPencilTool(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        board.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawPencilTool);
    }
```

This is how it is acting http://ugleh.com/DrawingApp4.swf

When I tried offsetting the results it didn't help much either for some reason.

Comment: Did you tried these : `board.mouseX` , `e.localX` , `e.stageX` ?

Comment: @Cherniv that worked, thank you so much. Which I could give you the answer, if you write it as an answer I can

Comment: Great , i've posted it like answer , thank you too

Comment: Which one of them worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try these properties  : `board.mouseX` , `e.localX` , `e.stageX`

Comment: Late answer to your last question but board.mouseX worked. I did not know mouseX or mouseY had its own start within the parent, I thought the parent was always the document.